# Using two updates where second update statement is using column from first update statement as input

Tags: sql, plsql

I've small doubt about update code block which has been written by someone before and now I'll be using it in my Java program.

`Is it possible to update a column first, then commit and afterwards use same column as an input in another update statement inside same block, as listed in below code.` I know using sub-query way to do this but have never seen this way before. It'll great if someone can confirm

**1)** Whether it is correct?

**2)** If not, what can be updated to make it work beyond using sub-query format.

**3)** Also, bas_capital_calc_cd is column in same table `derivatives` which is being updated. Can we pass column as an input to functions, such as `bas2_rwa_calc` here? Moreover, can we pass column name at all in plsql function as input.

Thanks in advance for help!

```
--BAS_EB_RWA_COMMT  is being used in BAS_EB_TOTAL_CAPITAL calculation. similarly, BAS_AB_RWA_COMMT  is being used in BAS_AB_TOTAL_CAPITAL calculation.

IF ID = 17 THEN     
     UPDATE derivatives 
             SET BAS_CAPITAL_CALC_CD = 'T',  
                 BAS_CATEGORY_CD =  case when nvl(rec.ssfa_resecure_flag,'N') = 'Y' then 911 else 910 end,
                 BAS_EB_RWA_COMMT = bas2_rwa_calc(bas_capital_calc_cd, v_SSFA_COMMT_AMT,v_BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K_COMMT, v_basel_min,v_bas_rwa_rate) + NVL(BAS_CVA_PORTFOLIO_RWA,0),
                 BAS_AB_RWA_COMMT = bas2_rwa_calc(bas_capital_calc_cd, v_SSFA_COMMT_AMT,V_BAS_CAP_FACTOR_K_COMMT, v_basel_min,v_bas_rwa_rate) + NVL(BAS_CVA_PORTFOLIO_RWA,0),
                 BAS_ICAAP_EB_RWA_COMMT = bas2_rwa_calc(bas_capital_calc_cd,bas_unused_commt,bas_icaap_factor_k_commt,v_basel_min,v_bas_rwa_rate),
           WHERE AS_OF_DATE = v_currect_DATE
          COMMIT;

          UPDATE derivatives 
             SET BAS_EB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = round(BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL(v_date, BAS_EB_RWA, BAS_EB_RWA_COMMT),2),
                 BAS_AB_TOTAL_CAPITAL = round(BAS2_MGRL_CAPITAL(v_date, BAS_AB_RWA, BAS_AB_RWA_COMMT),2)  
           WHERE AS_OF_DATE = v_DATE
             AND ID_NUMBER = rec.ID_NUMBER
             AND IDENTITY_CODE = rec.IDENTITY_CODE;
          COMMIT;
     WHERE AS_OF_DATE = v_currect_DATE;
    COMMIT;
END IF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DB2 and the SQL standard you use a feature called FINAL_TABLE to do this.  In Oracle you use a statement called "RETURNING".

cf - https://blog.jooq.org/tag/final-table/

Answer (score 1):

As I understood from your question statement you need to understand the `PLSQL`. Hoping, I got it correct.

To understand the concept let us first discuss what is a PL/SQL?

Theory Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/plsql-introduction/

PL/SQL is a block structured language that enables developers to combine the power of SQL with procedural statements.All the statements of a block are passed to oracle engine all at once which increases processing speed and decreases the traffic.

**Disadvantages of SQL:**

SQL doesn’t provide the programmers with a technique of condition checking, looping and branching.

SQL statements are passed to Oracle engine one at a time which increases traffic and decreases speed.

SQL has no facility of error checking during manipulation of data.

**Features of PL/SQL:**

PL/SQL is basically a procedural language, which provides the functionality of decision making, iteration and many more features of procedural programming languages.

> PL/SQL can execute a number of queries in one block using single
>   command.

One can create a PL/SQL unit such as procedures, functions, packages, triggers, and types, which are stored in the database for reuse by applications.

PL/SQL provides a feature to handle the exception which occurs in PL/SQL block known as exception handling block.

Applications written in PL/SQL are portable to computer hardware or operating system where Oracle is operational.

PL/SQL Offers extensive error checking.

Now please check the highlighted point **PL/SQL can execute a number of queries in one block using single command.**

Let us take an example of the situation you described.

```
create table test as select 0 as col1, 0 as col2 from dual;


declare
 v_col1 test.col1%type;
 v_col2 test.col2%type;

begin
 update test set col1 = col1 + 1;
 commit;

 dbms_output.put_line('col1='+v_col1);
 dbms_output.put_line('col2='+v_col2);

 update test set col2 = col1 + 1;
 commit;

 dbms_output.put_line('col1='+v_col1);
 dbms_output.put_line('col2='+v_col2);


end;
```

Please run above code, it is just a simple example of your question.

**Ans Point 1:** (Considering Oracle as sample database) So, according to me yes, it is possible, However, way you are writing these two updates, I am not sure that this is the best way or only way to handle such situations.

**Ans Point 3:** You can use Dynamic SQL to achieve the same in Oracle.

**Reference Link :** https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm